# WebToLead API returning error HTTP/1.1 400 TLS 1.1 or higher required

Tags: api

We have a service that is programmatically making requests to webtolead API to create leads. Our service is hosted in Azure Websites and we are making the request using System.Net.Http.HttpClient.
Lately some of the calls are failing with error Http 400 TLS 1.1 or higher required.
I could not find a way to set the TLS to 1.1 in an azure website. Please let us know if there is a workaround for this issue.

Comment: I think this is a question about Azure and should be asked on [so]?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable TLS1.1 or TLS1.2 by code in .Net, like this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

I have taken this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137106/are-there-net-implementation-of-tls-1-2

This is a more general C#/.Net question though.